# Failed to allocate nodeid for API at <ip-address>. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API)

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

i have configured mysql-cluster in centos 7

## Management Node

- db1 = 192.168.5.130

## Data Nodes

- db2 = 192.168.5.131
- db3 = 192.168.5.132

## SQL Nodes

- db4 = 192.168.5.133
- db5 = 192.168.5.134

output for management node as follows..

```
ndb_mgm> show
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @192.168.5.131  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=3    @192.168.5.132  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10, starting, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.5.135  (mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.5.133)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.5.134)
```

data node connected to management node sucessfully.. but sql node is **not connected**

i have see the some error in **ndb_1_cluster.log** file.

```
WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.5.134. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
```

How to resolve this issue ? Please guide me to configure mysql-cluster

Answer (score 1):

Check your `config.ini` in `/var/lib/mysql-cluster/` it should look something like this, should attach nodeid's if your working with more than 2 Data nodes. and most importantly make sure the data nodes your trying to run has `mysql.service` running. `systemctl mysql.service status`

```
[ndb_mgmd]
# Management process options:
hostname=10.10.12.184           # Hostname of the manager
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for the log files

[ndbd]
hostname=10.10.12.186           # Hostname of the 1st data node
nodeid=1;                       # Node id 1
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[ndbd]
hostname=10.10.12.187           # Hostname of the 2nd data node
nodeid=2;                       # Node id 2
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[ndbd]
hostname=10.10.12.188           # Hostname of the 3rd data node
nodeid=3;                       # Node id 3
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[ndbd]
hostname=10.10.12.189           # Hostname of the 4th data node
nodeid=4;                       # Node id 4
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
hostname=10.10.12.184  # In our case the MySQL server/client is on the same Droplet as$
```

In my experience, you should run all the ndbd nodes first then the sqld nodes on by one.